# Picklist with Angular JS parsing list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, repeat

I have a list of strings with years on it, like:

```
$scope.years = ["2001", "2002", "2003", ...];
```

I'm trying to render it on a page inside a `select` tag, but angular keeps breaking the code, rendering the elements outside the tag.

I have the following in the page:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>----</option>
    <option ng-repeat="y in years" value="{!y!}">{!y!}</option>
</select>
```

I does render, but all the option tags that are generated, are outside the select tag. Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: using AngularJS 1.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-options`, which is the recommended way in AngularJS, and has a lot of performance improvements over `ng-repeat` for this case.

It will require you to have `ng-model` as well. And you can still have your custom "Empty/Select" option.

It will look like this:

```
<select ng-model="something" name="S" 
        ng-options="y for y in years">
  <option value="" disabled selected>----</option>
</select>
```

A full working example:

```js
var app = angular.module("TestApp", []).controller("sample", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.years = ["2001", "2002", "2003"];
  }
]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ["TestApp"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="sample">
  <select ng-model="something" name="S" ng-options="y for y in years">
    <option value="" disabled selected>----</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**P.S.**

I'm assuming the `!` in your code is by mistake, if not, you cannot do this transformation in HTML. You better have another array with the formatted results, and watch the original array to update the transformation one.

Comment: I'm using ! in the code because Angular's default brackets are the same as Django's template engine, so when the page is rendered, double brackets don't exist anymore for angular to get the hooks. I changed the double brackets to bracket + ! and ! + bracket to avoid this.

Comment: Also, this didn't work for me. Well... kinda. Angular rendered it in the right place this time, but also rendered outside the tag. Thank you for your answer, but I needed to take another approach to this issue, because I'm a little out of time. This was just to make a pretty thing in the page, but wasn't necessary, so I dropped it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-options` instead

documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

sample plnkr for you here: https://plnkr.co/edit/tuKBJsxLxdUKcsRvWvax?p=preview

```
 <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="item for item in years"></select>
```